# Select top k records for each date

Tags: d3.js, crossfilter

My data is in the format [[date, value], ...].

For example:

`[[date1, value1], [date1, value2], [date2, value3], ....]]`

Say I want to select only 5 values for each date and those 5 values should be the top 5 values for that date.

What should my crossfilter/dimension look like?

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do this using pure D3 using [`d3.nest`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Arrays#d3_nest).

```
var topValuesByDate = d3.nest()
    .key(function(d){ return d.date; })
    .rollup(function(leaves){
        return leaves.map(function(d){
            return d.value;
        }).sort(d3.descending).slice(0, 5);
    })
    .entries(data);
```

The basic idea is to group values by date, then using a [`rollup`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Arrays#nest_rollup) to identify the top 5 values per date.

I also made [a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mdml/1e4yLrmy/) with simulated data constructed like so:

```
var data = [];
d3.range(1, 4).forEach(function(i){
    d3.range(10).forEach(function(j){
        data.push( {date: "2015/01/0" + i, value: j } );
    });
});
```